# Download only required js files using requirejs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, require

I am developing an application in which I have used requirejs and backbone on the frontend.

I have configured requirejs to load all the js files.

My main.js file looks something  like this :

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'js',
    paths: {
        "jquery": 'lib/jquery',
        "jquery.ui.widget" : "lib/jquery.ui.widget",
        "jquery.knob" : "lib/jquery.knob",
        "jquery.iframe-transport" : "lib/jquery.iframe-transport",
        "jquery.fileupload" : "lib/jquery.fileupload",
        "socket" : "lib/socket.io",
        "handlebars": 'lib/handlebars',
        "underscore": 'lib/underscore',
        "bootstrap" : 'lib/bootstrap',
        "backbone": 'lib/backbone',
        "views" : "views",
        "models" : "models",
        "collections" : "collections",
        "text" : "lib/helper/text"
    }
});

require(['jquery',
         'handlebars',
         'underscore',
         'backbone',
         'login',
         'jquery.ui.widget',
         'jquery.knob',
         'jquery.iframe-transport',
         'jquery.fileupload',
        ],function($,
                    Handlebars,
                    _,
                    Backbone,
                    Login){
    Login();
});
```

my login files looks like this :

```
define(function(require){
    return function(){
        var LoginView = require("views/login_view");
        $("#createAccount").click(function(){           
            $("#signInContainer").addClass("hide");
            $("#register").removeClass("hide");
        });
        var view = new LoginView({el : "body"});
    }
});
```

the view object is the Backbone.View object which starts as follows :

```
define(function(require){
    var User = require("models/user");
    var Dashboard = require("views/dashboard");

  //... rest of the code

}
```

The Login_view.js file has 2 other js files required in it.

Similarly all other pages that are going to be called after login also have such require statements in them.

The issue is :
When the page gets loaded all such nested requires gets downloaded. 
for eg. require statements within the Dashboard js file which is required in login also gets downloaded.

I want a solution through which I want only the initial files to get downloaded. files inside the dashboard should get downloaded only when i want to instantiate the dashboard object.

Comment: what does your `views/dashboard.js` file currently look like?

Comment: define(function(require){
                 var Template = require("text!/templates/dashboard.html");
                  var AddNoteDialog = require("views/add-note-dialog");
      .....
    }

so here when i refresh the page. these also gets downloaded because login -> requires dashboard -> and dashboard requires other files. so all files in the chain are called.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the code logic , and use requireJS to request a js file only on demand . See the below example which load the Dashboard when an user click on an element within page.

```
define(function(require){
    var User = require("models/user");  

  //...my code
 //ex on user click
 $("#myElement").on("click",function(){

     require(["views/dashboard"],function(Dashboard){

       //code for Dashboard here
     });
 });

}
```